# Communication between React.js and Rails Model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, reactjs, react-rails

**What i want to do ?**

I wan't to show on my rails view files data with react.js component from my rails models.

**What i have ?**

I have installed these gems

```
rails-admin
react-rails
```

**What i did ?**

I created a new rails project. 
I installed react-rails gem and rails-admin gem 
created new controller with following types

**rails g scaffold Post title:string body:text**

and i can add from rails admin posts all is okey.

my controller looking like :

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_post, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  # GET /posts
  # GET /posts.json
  def index
    @posts = Post.all
  end

  # GET /posts/1
  # GET /posts/1.json
  def show
    @post = Post.find(params[:id])
  end

  # GET /posts/new
  def new
    @post = Post.new
  end
```

and here is my views/posts/index.html.erb file

```
<%= react_component('PostList', {name: raw(render(template: 'posts/index', formats: :json)) }) %>
```

here is views/posts/index.json.jbuilder file

```
json.array!(@posts) do |post|
  json.extract! post, :id, :title, :body
  json.url post_url(post, format: :json)
end
```

here is views/posts/show.json.jbuilder file

```
json.extract! @post, :id, :title, :body, :created_at, :updated_at
```

here is my react component file assets/javascripts/components/post_list.js.jsx

```
var PostList = React.createClass({

  render: function() {  
    return (
      <div>
        {JSON.parse(this.props.posts).map(function(post) { 
          return <Post key={post.id} {... post}  />;
        })}
      </div>
      );
  }
});
```

So i can't understand where is i'm wrong. I can't get data from json to index.html.erb. How can i do that? Please help i'm stuck and i can't find nothing understandable on internet

Answer (score 1):

I made three changes to make it work:

1. index.html.erb

   ```
   <%= react_component('PostList',
             render(template: 'posts/index', formats: :json)
            )
    %>
   ```
2. views/posts/index.json.jbuilder file

   ```
   json.posts(@posts) do |post|
     json.extract! post, :id, :title, :body
     json.url post_url(post, format: :json)
   end
   ```

   as per instructed in the [documentation](https://github.com/reactjs/react-rails#jbuilder--react-rails); ie. "make sure your JSON is a stringified hash, not an array".
3. remove JSON.parse function in the PostList component render function, to this:

   ```
   var PostList = React.createClass({

      render: function() {
         return (
            <div>
              {this.props.posts.map(function(post) {
                 return <Post key={post.id} {... post}  />;
               })}
            </div>
          );
      }
   });
   ```

Answer (score 0):

this method is working.

**index.html.erb**

```
<% @news.order("id DESC").each do |news|  %>
                <%= react_component('News', { :news => news }) %>
                <% end %>
```

**news.js.jsx**

```
var News = React.createClass({

 displayName: 'News',

  render: function() {
    return (
           <div>
             <h4>{this.props.news.title}</h4>
             <p>{this.props.news.body}</p>
           </div>
    );
   }
 });
```

**index.json.jbuilder**

```
json.array!(@news) do |news|
  json.extract! news, :id, :title, :body
  json.url news_url(news, format: :json)
end
```